# Implementing array with partial cyclic data?

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays, data-structures

I'd like to construct an array where some columns are cyclic. As an illustrative example, take

`Table[Mod[k, 2^i], {k, 2^10}, {i, 0, 10}] //Grid`,

where the vast majority of cells are being used up by information where really only one little cycle needs to be stored for all but the last couple of columns. Once I crank that 10 up to 20 or 30, space becomes a concern.

Is this something I can/should do with SparseArray? Is there another method well suited for this? Or is this a case where I should roll my own wrapper function to handle it as best I can? Basically, I'd like to be able to treat this like a normal array for index-selection and everything, I just don't want to incur the memory hit.

Comment: do you need to modify/replace the elements of the array, or is it purely for access? if it's just for access, you might be better off with either a straight-up function to calculate it afresh each time! or if you want to avoid that, a function that mods-down the part specification appropriately, and then takes the relevant element of a precomputed list. (this could also be used for modification.) one way or another you could give some symbol upvalues for `Part`. Leaving this as a comment, though, because there might be a good built-in solution for this very thing out there somewhere...

Comment: Just use `Mod` when you index into the array. `RotateLeft` and `RotateRight` can also be helpful sometimes. But know that they copy the whole array, so use it wisely.